# Best way to Position A Form Relative to an Image

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am using HTML5 and would like to position an image on the left of the page and a form to the right of the image.  It would be relative positioning since the image may be any size.  Is CSS the best way to do this or are there better ways just using HTML?

I tried the following

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class='left'>
        <form action="javascript:ShowLoadedImage(document.getElementById('image-field').value);">
          <input type="file" accept="image/*" id="image-field" name="image" onchange="this.form.submit()">
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class='right'>
        <form>
            First name: <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
            Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname">           
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class='clear'></div>
</div>
```

but got the image below the form.  In fact I got a button, from subsequent code outside the  block, between them.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/float

Comment: Maybe another way to do it is to use a table with both in a table row but in different columns.  Alternatively, one would use JavaScript but some browsers have JavaScript disabled.

Comment: Tables should be used for tabular data, not layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with basic HTML/CSS:

**HTML:**

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class='left'>
        <form>
            <!-- your form -->
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class='right'>
        <!-- your image -->
    </div>
    <div class='clear'></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container {
    width: 300px;
}
.left {
    float:left;
}
.right {
    float:right;
}
.clear {
    clear:both;
}
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/SUEHs/

(I've provided multiple image sizes so you can see how elements flow).

Comment: I edited my initial question to show what I tried.  Unfortunately, it did not position the elements properly.  It put the image below the form.  Thanks, Peter.

Comment: @OtagoHarbour Make sure that the `left` and `right` divs fit into the container. For example, if your container is 900 pixels wide, you can try to set them to 400px each: `.left, .right {width:400px;}`